# Add records to SharePoint list from Excel VBA using shared link

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to create an Excel userform that will add new records to a SharePoint list.

This form needs to be available to all users in my organization, without being specifically permissioned to the list.

The basic URL for the SharePoint list looks something like this:
https://myorg.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/;LIST=SubmissionsTest;

This link only works for me. If I try to share the list, SharePoint provides a link that looks like this:
https://myorg.sharepoint.com/:l:/g/personal/myname/arandom50charactertextstring

Test users confirmed they can access the list via the second link, but not the first.

To push records into the list from Excel, I created the following VBA code:

```
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM SubmissionsTest;"

With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" _
    & "DATABASE=https://myorg.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/;LIST=SubmissionsTest;"
    .Open
End With
rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields("Title") = Int(Now() * 100000)
    rst.Fields("testEntry") = "This is a test submission"
    rst.Fields("testSubmitter") = Environ("UserName")
rst.Update

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close

MsgBox "Your submission has been received."
```

This code works when I run it. As expected, it does not run for my test users.

When I substitute that second, SharePoint-provided, link into the Connection String, the code no longer works either for me or my test users.
We receive an error telling us the SubmissionsTest object cannot be found.

Comment: Sharing links and direct permissions may work differently in this context - have you tried granting direct access to the list to your colleagues?

Comment: To Tim Williams: the problem is that I have 80,000 colleagues, any one of whom might need to use this form. I need to open it up to use by anyone in the firm.

Comment: You have 80k colleagues and no SharePoint administrators?

Comment: That's the problem in a nutshell. SharePoint is considered a "self-serve" technology. We have the ability to create our own SharePoint sites through Teams, but there is no formal support for it. It we use it, we have to figure out how to implement it ourselves.

Comment: It looks like the list is in your OneDrive?  If I go to set permissions on a list in my corporate OneDrive, I can add "Everyone except external users" and give them edit permissions on the list.  Does that work in your case?  If you just type "everyone" it should auto-complete.  I agree the concept of "self-serve" when it comes to Sharepoint is a little ridiculous given how complex it can be to get even basic things set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution after studying this posting on the Microsoft forums: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a1b718a-e9a5-4a1d-96a9-97804ebef769/vba-to-insert-record-to-an-existing-sharepoint-online-list?forum=sharepointgeneral

As indicated in the code above, the Connection String I was trying to use was:

```
DATABASE=https://myorg.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/;LIST=SubmissionsTest;
```

Even after permissioning the Sharepoint List for anyone in the firm, Excel reported that it was unable to find the table "SubmissionsTest". On the recommendation of the post above, I looked up the GUID values for the List. That returned a string that looked something like this:

```
<LIST><VIEWGUID>alongstringofalphanumericcharacters</VIEWGUID>
<LISTNAME>anotherstringofcharacters</LISTNAME>
<LISTWEB>https://myorg.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/</LISTWEB>
<LISTSUBWEB></LISTSUBWEB><ROOTFOLDER></ROOTFOLDER></LIST>
```

Once I changed the Connection String to this:

```
DATABASE=https://myorg.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/;LIST={anotherstringofcharacters};
```

the code now works for everyone. My conclusion is that, on SharePoint O365, table names cannot necessarily be trusted. Sometimes, the GUID values will need to be referenced directly.